# Python - Making a button change position randomly

Tags: python, user-interface, button, tkinter

I need to be able to change the button position when I click on it. The position changes by a random amount each time I click on it. But all i get is an error. Here's my code:

```py
from tkinter import *
from random import randrange

class Window(Frame):

    def position(self):
        return randrange(0,400),randrange(0,300)

    def __init__(self,master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.master = master
        self.__init__window()

    def __init__window(self):
        self.master.title("GUI")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        Button1 = Button(self, text="Click me if you can",command=self.Message)
        Button1.place(*position())
        menu=Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu=menu)
        file = Menu(menu)
        file.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.client_exit)
        menu.add_cascade(label="File",menu=file)
        edit = Menu(menu)
        edit.add_command(label="Show text", command=self.showText)
        menu.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=edit)

    def Message(self):
        print("Hello world")

    def showText(self):
        text = Label(self, text="Hey there!")
        text.pack()

    def client_exit(self):
        exit()

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x300")
app = Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

"Button1.place" is the position of the button that needs to be changed but I am completely clueless how else to do this. I used variables as well.

Comment: What error do you get? Please amend the question to include the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `place()` wants keyword arguments. You can let the function `position()` return a dict and unpack it in the `place()` statement:

```
def position(self):
    return {'x':randrange(0,400),'y':randrange(0,300)}
```

Placing the button with:

```
self.Button1.place(**self.position())
```

You also need to prefix the button name with "self" to be able to access it from outside the function `__init__window()`.

Then simply add a copy of the `place()` statement in the button callback function:

```
def Message(self):
    print("Hello world")
    self.Button1.place(**self.position())
```

That works fine for me at least (Python 3.6.5 under win10).

You'll have to reduce the random values generated for x and y or parts of the button will occationally be outside the window...

Comment: I still seem to be having problems now its giving me an error of place_configure() argument after ** must be a mapping, not method
where the button line goes. Ive made the changes but nothing has really changed.

Comment: I think you forgot the paranthesis on the `position()` function in the line: `self.Button1.place(**self.position())`.